# Will using a wallpowered usb cable to power a beaglebone black provide more power than on USB to computer?

Tags: usb, beagleboard, beaglebone-black

I couldn't find anything about this specific situation, but will it work, and are there any side effects that could damage it? Also, will it treat the USB as a computer?

Answer (score 1):

The charger will have the USB connection configured so that the device should not think that there is a host on the other end. As for the rest, I cannot put it any better than [Olin already has](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings). But long story short, as long as there is 5V at *at least* [460mA](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack#BeagleBone_Black_Description) plus additional current required by any capes and USB devices there will likely be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a power supply tester. I have measured many usb chargers. Many cheap ones only provide stable power up to about 70% of their rated capacity. So from a theoretical point-of-view you should be able to power the beaglebone from a 500mA charger, but in practise that might not be enough.

Similarly, many cheap USB cables have conductors that are too thin for the small usb-powered computers of today like the beagle bone black and the raspberry pi. So make sure you use a high quality cable.

About damaging anything: Most chips that are powered by 5V actually specify 5V +/- 10%. But some will specify 5V +/- 5%. Many USB chargers will give out 5.2-5.3V: just that little extra power to charge the cellphone with... In case there are 5V +/- 5% chips on the beaglebone that 5.3V would officially be outside spec, but in practise I don't think they will die.

Comment: The no-load output can be misleading when checking power supplies.  There may also be a touch of overvoltage to compensate for voltage drop through the charging cable length.  A dummy load is a valuable tool to check the output of power supplies over a range of loads that could also include the lead length.